# Python - "NameError: name 'filename' is not defined"

Tags: python, mongodb, nameerror

## Build mongoimport command

```
collection = filename[:filename.find('.')]  
working_directory = 'C:/Users/Anshuman Misra/Downloads/'  
json_file = filename + '.json'

mongoimport_cmd = 'mongoimport -h 127.0.0.1:27017 ' + \
                  '--db ' + db_name + \
                  ' --collection ' + collection + \
                  ' --file ' + working_directory + json_file
```

## Before importing, drop collection if it exists (i.e. a re-run)

```
if collection in db.collection_names():  
    print 'Dropping collection: ' + collection
    db[collection].drop()
```

## Execute the command

```
print 'Executing: ' + mongoimport_cmd  
subprocess.call(mongoimport_cmd.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you define `filename`? You are using it on the first line but I don't see where it was defined.

Comment: i added shell=True while invoking subprocess.call.The code works but the output is wrong i.e 0.

Comment: @AnshumanMisra , I don't understand what is the 0 output you are talking about. Is it the exit code of the entire program? If so, it's OK since it means the program was executed properly.

Comment: yes the exit code, and when i try to load a data base from collection it takes up the value zero. Itried putting "Anshuman Misra" in quotes still doesnt work