# this shows file not found,one of the problems is Anshuman Misra has a space in it how can i work with find

Tags: python, nameerror

## build mongoimport command

```
    collection = OSM_FILE[:OSM_FILE.find('.')] 
    working_directory = '/Users/Anshuman Misra/Downloads/'
    json_file = OSM_FILE + '.json'

    mongoimport_cmd = 'mongoimport -h 127.0.0.1:27017 ' + \
                      '--db ' + db_name + \
                      ' --collection ' + collection + \
                      ' --file ' + working_directory + json_file
```

## Before importing, drop collection if it exists (i.e. a re-run)

```
    if collection in db.collection_names():
        print 'Dropping collection: ' + collection
        db[collection].drop()
```

## Execute the command

```
    print 'Executing: ' + mongoimport_cmd
    subprocess.call(mongoimport_cmd.split(), shell=True)
```

Comment: if you dont add shell=True it shows file cant be found

Comment: there is space in `working_directory`, you should either quote it, or construct cmd as a sequence.

Comment: cany you elaoborate a bit i tried putting 'Anshuman Misra' in quotes before but it didnt work .I tried to work it externally on cmd it does show File till anshuman only @georgexsh

Comment: i can change working directory by adding quotes how can i make it work for collection its the same path as quotes

Comment: sorry, not clear what your new problem is, you should update the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - “NameError: name 'filename' is not defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47617718/354577)